# For Loop Swift: Cast from to unrelated type always fails

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

I have an error that says `Cast from '[String : AnyObject]' to unrelated type '[[String : AnyObject]]' always fails`

```
for dict in json as! [[String: AnyObject]] {
    let VideoCategory = videoCategory()
    VideoCategory.setValuesForKeys(dict)
    videoCategories.append(VideoCategory)
}
```

I tried wrapping it in an if statement, still it shows an error

What am I doing wrong?

here's the JSON feed

```
{
    "action":"videos",
    "result": {
        "count":2,"videos":
        [
            {
                "id":"427","asset_id":"279804413","asset_title":"title_1"
            }
            {
                "id":"428","asset_id":"279804413","asset_title":"title_2"
            }
        ]
}
```

Comment: You are trying to cast from a `Dictionary` to an `Array`, which won't work.

Comment: [String : AnyObject] is Dictionary & [[String:AnyObject]] is an Array! Also you need to write it as for dict in (json as! [[String: AnyObject]]) if your json is array containing dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Cast is like extracting/converting? So  should I check first if json is dictionary?

Comment: Please describe what you want to achieve, any post a sample of your JSON data. Your code and the error suggest that `json` is a dictionary, but you _think_ it actually is an array of dictionaries. Correct?

Comment: You better cast your json into [[String : AnyObject]] before you get into the "for loop". Add the code where you create your json variable, so it will be easier to understand where you're making the error.

Comment: @dr_barto - I've added a json feed

Comment: Thx for the JSON.. I assume you want to iterate over the values inside `result.videos` in the JSON, how are you loading and accessing that data?

Comment: @dr_barto from PHP, using session.datatask then JSONSerialization

Comment: I meant when you load the JSON in Swift: is `json` just the result of using `JSONSerialization`, or did you also drill down to the actual data? The JSON you posted _is no array_ at the top-level, so you cannot iterate it; instead you need to access the nested array like `json["result"]["videos"]` (that's pseudo-code, just to make the point).

Comment: I see, I'm using result->count for checking if there's a result in search controller
then, result->videos for looping it in the UICollectionView

yeah, I noticed that, I'm from PHP, I didn't know that you need to iterate it :( thanks for that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it right. I declared it as a string object first. Is
this a good approach?

```
let videos = json["result"] as! [String:AnyObject]

    for dict in videos["videos"] as! [[String: AnyObject]] {
           let VideoCategory = videoCategory()
           VideoCategory.setValuesForKeys(dict)
           videoCategories.append(VideoCategory)
    }
```